# Varnish in Ecommerce

Tags: magento, varnish

We're an e-commerce company running on Magento and evaluating whether we can use Varnish as an http cache. My biggest concern is that lot of our inventory / catalog data is very dynamic. To be precise, the price feed and inventory feed for the products updates our site every hour. Even merchandising (changing the order of products in categories) is done repeatedly and reflected every hour. For such a dynamic platform does Varnish make any sense? Would it require us to purge the cache every now and then?

Similarly, there are a lot of full page caching tools for Magento. But would they work in our use case?

Let me know if there's any other StackExchange forum where this question might make more sense.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your dynamic contents change every minute, it's worth it to use FPC. After all, you might have enabled the other caches either.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the amount of traffic you have. If you have "enough" traffic varnish can reduce your serverload drastically even if you can only cache for 1 hour.

For example we managed to dump half of our cluster just by caching 30 min with varnish.

Another solution would be to purge the urls which have new content on a crud action of an admin. Then you can increase the ttl to for example 24 hours which again will reduce server load and decrease load times. This will take quite some time to implement though.